# Crypto++ Ed448 unknown oid

Tags: crypto++, ecdsa

I have been trying to generate an Ed448 ECDSA key using crypto++ 7 from debian experimental. My code is as follows:

```
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
ECIES<ECP>::Decryptor d(rng, ASN1::curve448());
```

I can compile this code without errors, but when it runs, I get the following exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::UnknownOID'
  what():  BER decode error: unknown object identifier
```

Looking through the interwebs, It appears that curve448 was implemented last version. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been trying to generate an Ed448 ECDSA key... It appears that curve448 was implemented last version.

We added the OIDs for the 25519 and 448 curves some time ago. They were added to ease testing of curve25519 and ed25519. You can see the OIDs at [`oids.h`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/oids.h).

They OIDs were added at [Commit 7ca5f7d3b53f](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/7ca5f7d3b53f) on on Apr 11, 2016, and then subsequently fixed on the same day at [Commit 29e9bd2b27a9](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/29e9bd2b27a9). Apr 11, 2016 made them available to Crypto++ 5.6.4.

---

> I can compile this code without errors, but when it runs, I get the following exception

You are getting the exception because there are no domain parameters for curve448 in [`eccrypto.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/eccrypto.cpp#L457). You are hitting the exception below because `it == end`.

```
template <class EC> void DL_GroupParameters_EC<EC>::Initialize(const OID &oid)
{
    const EcRecommendedParameters<EllipticCurve> *begin, *end;
    GetRecommendedParameters(begin, end);
    const EcRecommendedParameters<EllipticCurve> *it = std::lower_bound(begin, end, oid, OIDLessThan());
    if (it == end || it->oid != oid)
        throw UnknownOID();

    const EcRecommendedParameters<EllipticCurve> &param = *it;
    m_oid = oid;
    ...
}
```

---

Here's the back story...

According to curve25519's [A state-of-the-art Diffie-Hellman function](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh.html), the source code for the curve is at [SUPERCOP](https://bench.cr.yp.to/supercop.html). SUPERCOP is a benchmarking program for cryptographic algorithms.

We have curve25519 and ed25519 on a testing fork. We ripped the implementation from SUPERCOP. SUPERCOP has the optimized reference implementations of curve25519, curve448, and lots of other stuff. Once curve25519 and ed25519 were added we planned on curve448.

We added curve25519 based on Andrew Moon's implementation. That provides `x25519` and `ed25519`. Also see [Issue 761](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/761) (x25519) and [Issue 764](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/764) (ed25519).

At this point the Crypto++ implementations of curve448 are stalled. I think your options are roll your own based on SUPERCOP, or use a library like `libsodium`, Botan or OpenSSL.

Comment: I switched to botan a couple of days ago. It doesn't have 448, but it has 25519. Once crypto++ supports it, I will have another go at trying to hook it up.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem @Cyclic. I believe Jack Lloyd used Adam Langley's [`curve25519-donna`](https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/pubkey/curve25519/donna.cpp). Jack is very attentive of Botan. You might consider making a feature request for curve448 at [Botan GitHub](https://github.com/randombit/botan). Unfortunately we a going to be stalled until we can safely remove the UB and get the team's sign-off.